# Proper exception handling with multiple Textfields

Tags: java, swing, exception, jtextfield

Image of the program: 
[program image](https://i.imgur.com/gYFqW0o)

This is is the code of the method called by the "+" button

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Calc extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JPanel contentPane;

private JTextField tf_1; // contains first operand
private JTextField tf_2; // contains second operand
private JTextField tf_3; // result

private JButton bu_1; // plus operation
private JButton bu_2; // multiplication

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Calc() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 387, 143);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    tf_1 = new JTextField();
    tf_1.setBounds(20, 35, 60, 20);
    contentPane.add(tf_1);
    tf_1.setColumns(10);

    tf_2 = new JTextField();
    tf_2.setBounds(90, 35, 60, 20);
    contentPane.add(tf_2);
    tf_2.setColumns(10);

    tf_3 = new JTextField();
    tf_3.setBounds(272, 35, 70, 20);
    contentPane.add(tf_3);
    tf_3.setColumns(10);

    //button 1
    bu_1 = new JButton("+");
    bu_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            addOperands();
        }
    });
    bu_1.setBounds(160, 34, 41, 23);
    contentPane.add(bu_1);

    //button 2
    bu_2 = new JButton("*");
    bu_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            multiplyOperands();
        }

    });;
    bu_2.setBounds(211, 34, 41, 23);
    contentPane.add(bu_2);

}

private void addOperands() {
    double value_1, value_2;
    try {
        value_1 = Double.parseDouble(tf_1.getText());

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        tf_1.setBackground(Color.red);
        tf_1.requestFocus();
    }
    try {
        value_2 = Double.parseDouble(tf_2.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tf_2.setBackground(Color.red);
        tf_2.requestFocus();
    }
    tf_3.setText(String.valueOf(value_1 + value_2));
}

private void multiplyOperands() {
    // TODO implement multiply operation
}
}
```

Currently I struggle to properly find out which textField throws the exception.
The code above doesn't work as the double values are not initialized.
But I don't want to just calculate with 0 if tf_X value is not a number.

I also tried to have `addOperands()` to return a double but 
returning `null` isn't possible in case of an exception.

What I want:

- not calculate a result if any value is not a number (NumberFormatException is thrown)
- set background to red of the textField that contains the NaN value
- clear current value of tf_3: `tf_3.setText("");`

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: `"Currently I struggle to properly find out which textField throws the exception..."` -- which text field throws **what** exception? And the exception stacktrace should tell you exactly what line is throwing it.

Comment: Also, you're asking why your code doesn't work, and to answer this well, we'll want to see more than a snippet and less than your whole code: consider creating and posting a [mcve] fully with your question. Please read the link to learn more about this useful tool.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels added full code

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't want to debug with stackTrace. I want to notify the user when a non double value is entered. So I need to distinguish which number value threw the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code of `addOperands`

```
private void addOperands() {
    double value_1, value_2;
    try {
        value_1 = Double.parseDouble(tf_1.getText());   
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        tf_1.setBackground(Color.red);
        tf_1.requestFocus();
    }
    try {
        value_2 = Double.parseDouble(tf_2.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tf_2.setBackground(Color.red);
        tf_2.requestFocus();
    }
    tf_3.setText(String.valueOf(value_1 + value_2));
}
```

when you are in the first `catch`

```
    try {
        value_1 = Double.parseDouble(tf_1.getText());   
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // here you know that tf_1 is non-double
        tf_1.setBackground(Color.red);
        tf_1.requestFocus();
    }
```

you know that first input contains bad input. The same about second input. If you don't want to show 0 as a result you have 2 choices: either stop processing on first error by simply putting `return` to the `catch` clauses or add flag(s) to see if everything is fine

```
private void addOperands() {
    double value_1, value_2;
    boolean good = true;
    try {
        value_1 = Double.parseDouble(tf_1.getText());   
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        good = false;
        tf_1.setBackground(Color.red);
        tf_1.requestFocus();
    }
    try {
        value_2 = Double.parseDouble(tf_2.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        good = false;
        tf_2.setBackground(Color.red);
        tf_2.requestFocus();
    }
    if(good)   
       tf_3.setText(String.valueOf(value_1 + value_2));
    else
       tf_3.setText("Bad input");   
}
```

**Update**

If you want to decompose your code (and usually this is a good idea), you could do something like this

```
private Double readDoubleOrHighlight(JTextField tf) {
    try {
        double res = Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());   
        tf.setBackground(whatever-default-background-is);
        return res;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        tf.setBackground(Color.red);
        tf.requestFocus();
        return null;
    }
}

private void addOperands() {
    Double value_1 = readDoubleOrHighlight(tf_1);
    Double value_2 = readDoubleOrHighlight(tf_2);
    if((value_1 != null) && (value_2 != null))
       tf_3.setText(String.valueOf(value_1 + value_2));
    else
       tf_3.setText("Bad input");   
}
```

Note: Here I effectively use `Double` as `Option[double]` that is not supported in Java anyway (hint: google `Option`, it is a powerful idea or start at [Option type in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type)).

**Update #2**

This time introducing higher-order functions.
If you add a piece of code like this

```
static interface BinaryOp {
   double calc(double arg1, double arg2);
}

private void applyBinaryOp(BinaryOp op) {
    Double value_1 = readDoubleOrHighlight(tf_1);
    Double value_2 = readDoubleOrHighlight(tf_2);
    if((value_1 != null) && (value_2 != null)) {
       double res = op.calc(value_1, value_2);
       tf_3.setText(res);
    }
    else
       tf_3.setText("Bad input");   
}
```

you can simplify your click listenrs to something like this

```
    bu_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            applyBinaryOp(new BinaryOp(){
               public double calc(double arg1, double arg2) {
                   return arg1 * arg2;
               }
            });
        }
    });
```

And with Java 8 lambda syntax it is even simpler.

Comment: @ftp.x32, please see my update. It might simplify your code very much

Comment: hint: google `Option`?? Of the 2 billion results, which one(s) should the OP check out?

Comment: @SergGr I implemented your Update#1 now. But I kind of think Update#2 is going a bit too far for this simple task isn't it?

Comment: @ftp.x32 it depends on your task. The good thing about Update #2 is that it better separates "logic" and "UI". Because of this there is much less code duplication and it is easier to add new operations or change UI (such as replace JTextField with something else). On the other hand you should put a limit somewhere to your perfectionism. My main idea actually was to introduce such an idea to show that further separation is possible even if it is not required in this small task

Comment: @SergGr Thanks for the explaination. Sadly I failed with trying to introduce your solution as shown in Update#2. Or the code might not be correct. Calling `calc(double arg1, double arg2)` in bu_2s actionListener
doesn't really work. I can pass the textfield values there but it's done again when calling `applyBinaryOp`. Unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @ftp.x32 The idea of the code is not to call `calc` directly inside the actionListener. Interface `BinaryOp` represents a function (double,double)=>dobule i.e. one that gets 2 double arguments and returns double result. `applyBinaryOp` is a method that gets any such function and uses it to calculate and show the result on UI. What your action listener needs to do is to create an objet of the `BinaryOp` interface representing corresponding mathematical operation (and I do it using one more anonymous class) and just pass it to the `applyBinaryOp`. I just re-checked the syntax and it looks OK.